# What is the best way to handle rogue waves?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

While I am battling in the seas of Assassin's Creed 4, occassionally a rogue wave will pound my ship!  I take massive damamge and end up losing a few crew members.

Can I avoid the massive wave or what should I do when a massive wave is coming?

Are there any *tells* in the game that I can know if a massive wave is coming?

Is there anyway to get my crew back once they are lost to rogue wave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the minimap a rogue wave icon does appear and shows which direction it is traveling.  And to avoid losing crew members you hold the 'X' button(on Xbox), <kbd>Space</kbd> on PC, Y(on Wii U), or Square(on PS3) but that will brace the crew and you won't take as much damage.

Also, You can get more crew by going to a tavern, helping pirates in the locations, or picking up castaways in the open sea.

As some have stated in the comments, another way to avoid damage from the rogue waves is to face them head on.  But in my experience it is just easier and quicker to brace and then get back to the battle.

Comment: Is there anyway to get your crew back?

Comment: You can get more crew by going to a tavern, helping pirates in the locations, or picking up castaways in the open sea.

Comment: Best way (and the way I've always used) is to drive straight into the wave and you don't take any damage at all.

Comment: The Brace button is Y on Wii U. Based on all that information, I'd guess that it'll always be the left face button, so Square on PS3

Answer (score 13):

> Can I avoid the massive wave or what should I do when a massive wave is coming?

Keep an eye on the minimap to see which direction the wave is coming from. If you are able, turn to face the wave head on and you will take no damage at all. Lowering the sails to slow down will make turning easier.

If you can't turn in time, hold <kbd>X</kbd> (or equivalent on platforms that aren't Xbox) to brace for impact and take less damage.

> Are there any tells in the game that I can know if a massive wave is coming?

It's mostly just the minimap. I think sometimes someone will also yell about a wave coming, but I'm not sure if that happens every time.

> Is there anyway to get my crew back once they are lost to rogue wave?

Just the same ways that you'd acquire crew in the first place - rescue missions around cities, rescuing castaways, and recruiting from taverns.

Comment: I think so far I have always had crew warning me of rogue waves. And of course they only occur in stormy weather (in my experience) so you should be on the lookout for them more then.

Comment: Also worthy of note is a reminder that if you are travelling slower you will turn quicker making it easier to face the wave.

Comment: This is the more complete answer and should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

A alt way to handle a rogue wave is facing it up front, the bracing is not compulsory when using this strategy and if you fail to do this tactic, you can recruit pirates by.

1. Helping pirates in the world eg: shipwrecked pirates.
2. Recruiting them at a tavern.
3. Boarding a ship and selecting any option.

The bracing is usually used as a last resort if you fail to face the rogue wave up front.